# How to optimize the opening speed of admin panel?

Tags: wp-admin, wp-user-query

Now my access to the WordPress post editing page is abnormally slow and I have to wait 30 seconds or more for it to finish loading each time.

Initially, I thought it was a problem with the network environment, but I tried to change to a different network to access it and still reproduce the problem.

So I troubleshot the server resource usage and found that the `mysqld` process puts the cpu at 100% high occupancy when accessing the post editing page.

Then I upgraded the server configuration, but the problem did not improve, so I ran `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` command to check and got the following result.

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id    | User        | Host      | db      | Command | Time | State                    | Info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | Progress |
+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|     1 | system user |           | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |    0.000 |
|     2 | system user |           | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |    0.000 |
|     3 | system user |           | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |    0.000 |
|     4 | system user |           | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |    0.000 |
|     5 | system user |           | NULL    | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |    0.000 |
| 22012 | root        | localhost | NULL    | Query   |    0 | Init                     | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |    0.000 |
| 20307 | root        | localhost | wpdb    | Query   |    2 | Creating sort index      | SELECT wp_users.ID,wp_users.user_login,wp_users.display_name FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value != '0' ) ) ORDER BY display_name ASC    |    0.000 |
+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

This seems to indicate that the problem is because querying the user list takes a lot of time. My WordPress site does have a lot of registered users (50K+).

Is this a known issue with WordPress? How should I fix it?

Any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because it was running that particular query at that particular time does not mean that's the query that was slow. You don't currently have enough information to diagnose why the page is loading slow, or which queries are slow. If it is that query that is slow then that implies you have billions of users which is extremely unlikely. That query is not a common WordPress issue.

Comment: This can be quite difficult to debug. Many plugins do a lot of (unnecessary) things inside WP admin - that works for small sites but larger sites soon experience problems. Can you use sth like Debug Bar on a staging instance and check if there are any large/slow queries?

Comment: @TomJNowell I saw a similar problem online, but this is an old thread https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28160

Comment: @kero I think my site is quite common (a multi-user article publishing platform), not running complex features (using only the features provided by WordPress, no secondary development), and not installing too many plugins.

Comment: In my case, the problem recurs steadily (when creating a new post or editing a post).

Comment: There are widespread tools for tracking slow queries such as the MySQL slow query log, plugins such as debug bar or query monitor, etc. There's not enough information in the question to identify the cause or implicate that particular query. It could even be that the queries are super fast but there are a huge number of them